# How to port forward successfully & mask between internal & external ports

Tags: port-forwarding, bittorrent

When my bittorent client uses port 6881-6889 as listening port I suppose that is the internal port? How does one mask bittorrent client from ISP's?

For example can I use virtual server configuration using external port 60000 to 60050 to connect to internal port 6881-6889 (on my computer) to mask bittorrent service? I ask as my ISP has throttled 6881-6889.

Is my understanding right. My router does not have port forwarding. Only port triggering and virtual servers are available.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP probably does not throttle by port, but by packet inspection. Either way, you should use a client that can A)Randomize the port used, B)Encrypt the traffic so that it can't be inspected. This way you shouldn't be throttled.

Comment: The only problem with port randomization, is that your router must enable UPNP, which can be a serious security vulnerability in some circumstances, so that must be considered before choosing to implement the feature.